# How to start a VM though Vagrant

Tags: linux, macos, centos, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have never used Vagrant before. Now, Im investigating to use it for my project.
Here is my problem so need some help from every one.

Currently , I have a CentOS guest that has been installed via Virtual Machine in MAC host. Im going to install Vagrant into MACbook then I want to use Vagrant command line for control CentOS by terminal. 
As far as I know, after install Vagrant we have to add a box then start up this box ( Windows, *Unix,...). So in my case I ALREADY have a CentOS VM , I do NOT want add a box (because I have to install all of package, soft again).
How to integrate the current CentOS with vagrant ?

Please help me if you know. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to create a "base box", as it's known in vagrant, is all there in the documentation: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/boxes.html

Honestly though, if you're new to it all, I would advise that it would be easier to start with vagrant and a fresh CentOS VM, rather than the approach you're trying.  e.g.:

```
$ vagrant init chef/centos-7.1
$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

The installation of packages, software etc can all be defined in the Vagrantfile (see: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/).

This approach avoids ending up with a [snowflake server](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SnowflakeServer.html).

Comment: I already have a CentOS VM. I don't want to create a new one.
So, how to add existed CentOS VM to vagrant ?

Comment: Thank you so much ! I found it ^^

Answer (score 0):

By far, the easiest way to configure and use virtual machines is with [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/).  Check it out!

Comment: You should know, that Vagrant isn't intended to be an administrative tool for existing boxes.  It's meant to make boxes portable, manageable and disposable.

Comment: I think this is impossible.  Vagrant is used to create a virtual machine.  There is no way to use an existing virtual machine to create a Vagrantfile.